# A hard core spatial point process that a vehicle encounters as Poisson arrivals?

Tags: stochastic-processes, spatial, poisson-process, point-process

Does there exist a point process $X$ in the plane with the following two properties?

1. *$X$ is hard core*. Discs of radius $h$ can be centered on the points in $X$ without overlapping.
2. *$X$ is encountered as Poisson arrivals*. Propel a disc of radius $r \leq h$ at constant velocity along a randomly selected line across the plane. For any time that the disc does not contain a point from $X$, let $T$ be the time to the disc's next encounter with a point from $X$. Then $T$ has an exponential distribution.

Property (2) on its own is satisfied by a Poisson point process.  Indeed in this case the caveat of "For any time that the disc does not contain a point from $X$" can be weakened to "At any time".

My intuition is that a suitably specialized Strauss process might do the job?  But I can't see how to establish this, or discussion in literature.  Many thanks.

Comment: 1. Poisson hard core (a Gibbs model), and Matérn's hard core point processes are other easy to understand model that fulfil 1.
2. how does the disc move across the plane? on a randomly chosen line, or zigzag or in yet another way? and what do you mean by *whenever* the disc does not contain... is it to be understood as "for any time" where the disc is empty?

Comment: @Ute. The disc is propelled at constant velocity along a randomly chosen line (I have made an edit).  And yes, "for any time" when the disc is empty.

Comment: I have no solution at hand, but your question about the disc translates into: "the germ grain model resulting from attaching balls of radius r to X has exponential linear contact distribution". Maybe "linear contact distribution" is a key word that helps here.

Comment: I wonder if there exists a point process that fulfils the requirement "exponential linear contact distribution" for all r < h. interesting question! +1 :-) What is the context?(just curious)

Comment: (obviously, I meant a non Poisson point process)

Comment: The context is deploying sensors over a region to detect an intruder. Each disc is the coverage of a sensor. How might they be deployed so that 1) they don’t overlap (to avoid wastage), and 2) even if the intruder realizes that they are in range of one sensor, they don’t get insight into where the other sensors are (to avoid them)? Thanks heaps again for the suggestions.

Comment: cool, thank you :-)